# Is it possible to have collision resistance but not pre-image and 2nd pre-image resistance?

Tags: collision-resistance, preimage-resistance

I have studied cryptographic hash functions quite a lot, but have not completely understood whether it is possible to have collision resistance but not pre-image and 2nd pre-image resistance at the same time.

Is it possible?

Please answer this question with a general example.

Comment: Please see [this link](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/69405) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28378326).

Answer (score 3):

No, any second preimage creates a collision. So collision resistance implies 2nd preimage resistance.